# Instagram API using Python and collecting comments from each caption

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently trying out to use Instagram API using Python. I manage to collect comments from each caption, but I can only manage to collect a maximum of 8 comments from each caption. Some of the caption have 30+ comments, but I only collect the last 8 comments out of those 30+ comments.

Is there anything wrong with my code? Is there anyway to collect more than 8 comments per caption?

My codes are:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
import re

access_token = "XXX"
client_secret = "XXX"

api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="476132155")

for media in recent_media:
    try:
        comments = media.comments

        for i in comments:
            print i.text, " --> ", i.user.username
            print ""

except (UnicodeEncodeError, AttributeError, SyntaxError):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct if you wanted to fetch the `Media` Objects only. If you're specifically targeting the comments, you'll have to fetch them with information from each `Media` Object individually.

[From The Docs](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/): Use the `id` of a `Media` Object to call the comments-api. In order to do that you should retrieve each `id` in your `for-loop`:

```
for media in recent_media:
  comments = api.media_comments(media.id)
  # do something with comments here
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried using it but it still collect maximum of 8 comments per caption, but this time is the first 8 comments, and not last.

My code are:

for media in recent_media:
  comments = api.media_comments(media.id)

for i in comments:
   print i.text, "--->", i.user.username

Comment: however, if i tried print i, it print out everything. Thank you!

Comment: sorry but one last question, how do i get comment_created by the users who commented? i tried i.comment_created but it does not work. However, I am able to only get comment_created the owner itself: media.comment_created. Is there anyway for me to collect created_time by user who commented? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you need. Open another question, specify your problem there and post your current code, which is your current not working solution so that others have the chance to help you too ;)